# C Printf in while and if loop print twice

Tags: c, printf

I'm making a C program that display active foreground window but i have got a problem as mentionned in the topic, it prints twice all string beside (%s, new_window). I've read many topic about this printf problem but none of them does work for me. Here is my code

```
int main() {
    char window[256]= "hello";
    char new_window[256] = "hello";
    HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowText(handle, window, 256);
    //different
    while(1){
        HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        GetWindowText(handle, window, 256);
        if(strcmp(window, new_window)) {
            strcpy(new_window,window);
            if (strcmp(window, new_window)){
                 printf("%s Active: \n", new_window);
                 fflush(stdout);

            }
            else {
             printf("%s Active: \n", window);
             fflush(stdout);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output example when i switch windows (here netbeans and firefox):

> ```
>     CLab - NetBeans IDE 8.2 Active: 
>      Active: 
>     ZeroDay - Mozilla Firefox Active: 
>      Active: 
>     CLab - NetBeans IDE 8.2 Active: 
>      Active: 
>     ZeroDay - Mozilla Firefox Active: 
>      Active: 
>     CLab - NetBeans IDE 8.2 Active:
> ```

Output i want:

> ```
>     CLab - NetBeans IDE 8.2 Active: 
>
>     ZeroDay - Mozilla Firefox Active: 
>
>     CLab - NetBeans IDE 8.2 Active: 
>
>     ZeroDay - Mozilla Firefox Active: 
>
>     CLab - NetBeans IDE 8.2 Active:
> ```

Comment: How can Your program exit from the while(1) loop?

Comment: It won't exit the while loop, it will keep running until the process is down

Comment: @MichaelWalz It won't exit the while loop and i don't want it to exit this loop for now, this code is some kind of keylogger mixed with what is typed in what window, my problem is just about printf which prints twice

Comment: @MikaelWalz oh yeah, ok, sorry :)

Comment: Please add comments to explain the logic of your "if-branches", something like `// different, i.e. window has been changed`, `// identical, i.e. no change of window`. Especially the "if" right after copying on to the other. You might also want to change your output slighlty, so that is is always obvious which line is the source of the output. And something like markes for showing the start and end of the printed window text. It looks to me like you are somehow not switching between two windows, but three, one of which has an empty window text. Maybe you can somehow output handle, too.

Comment: Check your c library for the return value of strcmp.  I don't think it is a Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get how the second `strcmp(window, new_window)` could be equal to something else than **0** as you do a `strcpy` right before it. It seems that you'll always get into the `else` statement.

I think that the problem is that after getting into the second `if strcmp(window, new_window)` and printing what you want, you do another loop where `window = ""` So you print twice *"Active:"*.

Try to :

> 1. Change the second if to `if( !strcmp(window, new_window) && strcmp(window, ""))`
> 2. Delete the else.

Edit: Deleted a `!` that make the if condition wrong

Comment: indeed, it 'll always get into the else statement. I use the second if to prevent the while loop to print infinite string. I tried to change the second if to if( !strcmp(window, new_window) && !strcmp(window, "")), it displays one time but only "Active: " and not the active windows name

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it works :D, thank you sir, i changed to > if( !strcmp(window, new_window) && strcmp(window, ""))